# String replace 0 with 1.7E

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2012, replace

Hey guys im trying to replace a string value of 0 with 1.7E.
So say you have a string like the following

```
data=0,101,1,0
```

When i do the following:

```
Dim data_source As String = Request.QueryString("data")
Dim strContent As String = data_source.Replace("0", "1.7E")
```

it's producing the results of 1.7E,**11.7E1**,1,1.7E
What i actually need is it to convert to the following
1.7E,101,1,1.7E
So im trying to figure out how to get it to target only )'s that have no trailing or leading numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Also i should mention that the values are being dynamically populated from a database.

Comment: _"the values are being dynamically populated from a database"_ How is that related to the question? Maybe you should modify the sql query instead. But sql queries which yield a string with comma separated integers are suspect. I hope that you don't store them as string.

Comment: they are values being pulled from a database, that are being passed as queries on an image tag to a charting software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split first by comma, then build the new strings and finally join them:

```
Dim token As String() = data.Split(","c)
Dim newToken = From t In token Select If(t = "0", "1.7E", t)
Dim strContent As String = String.Join(",", newToken)
```

The second statement is a LINQ query, so you need to add `Imports System.Linq`.